# File transfer help with Ubuntu and ESXi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, file-copy

I have two esxi machines that I want to directly transfer files between.  Is there a way I can facilitate that transfer from a third machine that I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on?

Comment: Could you be more specific?